# Is my Bash command syntax of `command && break` correct?

Tags: bash, build

In my Jenkins build, when I push a local PR to Master, `blackduck` scanning in the Master branch often fails. And so I would like to introduce some code to get it to retry if it fails. I looked online and found a useful `command && break` syntax, but I'm not sure if I am using it correctly.

Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ex

. "${0%/*}/common.sh"
. activate "$PYENV_HOME"
for ((i=0;i<5;++i));
do
  if [[ "$BRANCH_NAME" == "master" || "$BRANCH_NAME" == "main" ]]; then
    DETECT_PROJECT_VERSION_NAME="$BRANCH_NAME"
    DETECT_PROJECT_VERSION_PHASE="PRERELEASE"

    bash <(curl -s https://artifactory.dev.com/artifactory/blackduck-detect/detect7.sh) \
      --blackduck.url=https://com_name.app.blackduck.com \
      --blackduck.api.token="${BLACKDUCK_API_TOKEN}" \
      --detect.project.name="${DETECT_PROJECT_NAME}" \
      --detect.project.version.name="${DETECT_PROJECT_VERSION_NAME}" \
      --detect.project.version.phase="${DETECT_PROJECT_VERSION_PHASE}" \
      --detect.code.location.name="${DETECT_PROJECT_NAME}_${BRANCH_NAME}" \
      --detect.source.path="$(pwd)" \
      --detect.excluded.directories=/tests/
      && break
  fi
  sleep 15 
done
```

Another quick question if I may; after introducing the code, I would like to test this locally, so it possible to simply change the `"$BRANCH_NAME"` to my local PR branch's name?

I found this link that was helpful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82598/how-do-i-write-a-retry-logic-in-script-to-keep-retrying-to-run-it-upto-5-times

But can I substitute my whole code for `command`?

Comment: Please don't ask two things in one question. `some_command && break` executes the _break_, if `some_command` ends with exit code zereo. However, IMO, your `set -e` would then be pointless (not 100% sure about it, since I never use `-e`).

Comment: Technically, no. The last line of the `bash` command either needs a line continuation, or the `&&` has to appear on the same line as the final `--detect` option. A line feed will terminate a command; a `&&` will not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is my Bash command syntax of `command && break` correct?

Yes.

The exit status of `if` is `0`, when there is no `else` block and the condition if false, or the exit status of the whole `if` block is equal to the exit status of the last command executed. So if the condition is false, then `&& break` will break, if the condition is true, then `bash <(curl` will execute and will `&& break` depending on the exit status.

I would refactor it to just `bash <(curl..... && break`. I would also just `for i in $(seq 5)` or `for ((i=0;i<5;++i))` instead of `while`. I see no reason to do `if [ "$BRANCH_NAME" == "master"...` every loop. Also prefer `if` instead of `&&`. Check your scripts with shellcheck. Additionally, you can use `$PWD` instead of `$(pwd)`.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ex

. "${0%/*}/common.sh"
. activate "$PYENV_HOME"
if [[ "$BRANCH_NAME" == "master" || "$BRANCH_NAME" == "main" ]]; then
    DETECT_PROJECT_VERSION_NAME="$BRANCH_NAME"
    DETECT_PROJECT_VERSION_PHASE="PRERELEASE"
    for ((i=0;i<5;++i)); do
        if 
           bash <(curl -s https://artifactory.dev.com/artifactory/blackduck-detect/detect7.sh) \
           --blackduck.url=https://com_name.app.blackduck.com \
           --blackduck.api.token="${BLACKDUCK_API_TOKEN}" \
           --detect.project.name="${DETECT_PROJECT_NAME}" \
           --detect.project.version.name="${DETECT_PROJECT_VERSION_NAME}" \
           --detect.project.version.phase="${DETECT_PROJECT_VERSION_PHASE}" \
           --detect.code.location.name="${DETECT_PROJECT_NAME}_${BRANCH_NAME}" \
           --detect.source.path="$PWD" \
           --detect.excluded.directories=/tests/
        then
           break
        fi
   done
fi
```

> so it possible to simply change the "$BRANCH_NAME" to my local PR branch's name?

It's just a variable, set it and export.

```
BRANCH_NAME=stuff ./yourscript
```

> But can I substitute my whole code for command?

Generally yes. Research command exit status in bash

Comment: Thank you so much Kamil, I was just refactoring my code, but noticed you have written the refactor code. Much appreciated. One question, when you mention `set it and export`, what did you mean by `export`?

Comment: Perhaps also avoid downloading the script via `curl` repeatedly. Surely it should be sufficient to download it once, and then try running it from a local copy?

Comment: `what did you mean by export?` It sounds like a basic question, I am sure you can input `bash export` in google and you'll find many links. Google found for me https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/export-command-linux https://phoenixnap.com/kb/bash-export-variable .

Comment: Thanks for your help and time Kamil, I will look through the pages